# How to do a grep on remote machine and print out the line which contains those words?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, grep

I have few logs files in my `machineB` under this directory `/opt/ptd/Logs/` as shown below - My logs files are pretty big.

```
david@machineB:/opt/ptd/Logs$ ls -lt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  49651720 Oct 11 16:23 ptd.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 104857728 Oct 10 07:55 ptd.log.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 104857726 Oct 10 07:50 ptd.log.2
```

I am trying to write a generic shell script which should try to parse all my log file in `machineB` for a particular pattern and print the line which has those patterns. I will be running my below shell script from `machineA` which has all the ssh keys setup everything meaning I need to remotely grep on the logs files on machineB from machineA.

```
#!/bin/bash

wordsToInclude="hello,animal,atttribute,metadata"
wordsToExclude="timeout,runner"

# now grep on the various log file for above words and print out the lines accordingly
```

Meaning, I will have words separated by comma in `wordsToInclude` variable - If my logs contain `hello` word then print out that line, also print out the line which contains `animal` word. Similarly with `attribute` and `metadata` words.

And also I will have words separated by comma in `wordsToExclude` variable - If any of the lines contains those words then don't print out those line.

I am going with the above format for now for storing the words but any better format is fine to me. I can have long list of words in `wordsToInclude` and `wordsToExclude` variable so that's why I am going with storing them in those variables.

I know how to do a grep on small set of variables. If I need to do grep from the command line directly on machineB, then I will do it like this -

```
grep -E 'hello|animal|atttribute|metadata' ptd.log | grep -v 'timeout'
```

But I am not sure how do I combine this in my shell script so that I can do a remote ssh grep on machineB from machineA.

Comment: Too bad there are so many questions implied in this question.

Answer (score 8):

If you are open to other formats, consider:

```
inc="hello|animal|atttribute|metadata"
exc="timeout|runner" 
ssh machineB "grep -E '$inc' path/ptd.log | grep -vE '$exc'"
```

#### Faster Alternative

If your log files are large and you are grepping for fixed words, as opposed to fancy regular expressions, you may want to consider this approach:

```
inc='hello
animal
atttribute
metadata'

exc='timeout
runner'

ssh office "grep -F '$inc' ptd.log | grep -vF '$exc'"
```

By putting each word on a separate line, we can use grep's `-F` feature for fixed strings.  This turns off regex processing, making the process faster.

Answer (score 2):

It may not seem possible but you can make use of `grep`'s `-f` option to make use of that list of words, even though they're in a environment variable and not a proper file. The trick is in fooling `grep` into thinking that they are from a file like so:

```
$ ssh machineB 'grep -f <(echo $wordsToInclude|tr , "\n") file1 file2 file3'
```

This will run the `grep ...` command remotely via `ssh` on machineB. It will take your variable, `$wordsToInclude` and switch the commas to end of line characters, (`,` -> `\n`). This list of words is then fed into `grep` via its `-f` switch.

To run this through the exclude list simply add that as a 2nd grep after the initial one via a pipe.

```
$ ssh machineB 'grep -f <(echo $wordsToInclude|tr , "\n") \
    file1 file2 file3 | grep -vf <(echo $wordsToExclude)'
```

Answer (score 1):

SSH is run with a command like so:

```
ssh host command
```

Or in your case:

```
ssh -t machineB "grep -E \"$wordsToInclude\" ptd.log | grep -v \"$wordsToExclude\""
```

The `-t` prevents an "ioctl error". I'd also recommend using grep's fixed words for increased speed, as specified by [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/161645/306237) by @John1024. Just put each word on it's own line, like:

```
wordsToInclude='hello
animal
atttribute
metadata'

wordsToExclude='timeout
runner'
```

And add `-F` to grep's options.